# OpenGL VBO - load a normals index

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

Okay I have the following code that works correctly. It loads a vertex array, a normal array and a vertex index array then draws them with some simple light shading.

To load the buffers:

```
//Load Buffers
//vertices
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verts.size() * sizeof(verts), &verts[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW); //verts is std::vector<float>
//normals
glGenBuffers(1, &normalbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normals.size() * sizeof(normals), &normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW); //normals is std::vector<float>
//indices
glGenBuffers(1, &elementbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(GLushort), &indices[0] , GL_STATIC_DRAW);
//indices is std::vector<unsigned short> and in this working example only
//contains indices into the vertex array (I will add interleaved normal indices)
```

To draw the buffers:

```
//Draw Object
glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
glEnableClientState( GL_NORMAL_ARRAY );

//vertices
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

//Indices
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementbuffer);

//Normals
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbuffer);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, (void*)0 );

//Draw the mesh
glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (void*)0);

//Clean up
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

In this code, normals are not indexed. I would like to change it so that the normals are based on the the index in `indices[]` (same as vertices are now). `indices[]` is interleaved (not in the above code) as such: {vertex index,normal index,vertex index,normal index...}.

I've been trying to get this to work for some time without success and every example I've found online seems to use a different approach to VBOs making it very difficult to combine multiple examples into one that does what I need.

Help would be greatly appreciated. And if I'm doing anything in a less than ideal way, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: "*every example I've found online seems to use a different approach to VBOs making it very difficult to combine multiple examples into one that does what I need.*" Maybe you should focus on [understanding how those examples *work*](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification), and not so much on trying to combine their code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In this code, normals are not indexed.

They most certainly are. They merely share the same index as the position.

What you want is not generally possible. All vertex attributes *must* use the same index. You must convert your multi-indexed data to single-indices per vertex.

[There are techniques you could use to avoid this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148567/rendering-meshes-with-multiple-indices), but they generally require semi-advanced hardware and will lower your overall vertex throughput performance.

Comment: oh, so the standard wavefront .obj format doesn't work with VBOs without some rearranging.

Comment: ah, the "note:" under "vertex stream" in the link you provided in your comment says exactly that. Thanks.